# Alert to another app with ionic 3 and cordova 8

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I want to send and alert from an app to another one. I'm developing both applications and they are talking, but I'm confusing in this alert question. Here is my code:

```
<ion-item style="align-items: center;">
  <button color="green" ion-button (click)="presentAlert()">
    <ion-icon name="alert"></ion-icon>&nbsp; {{'o que quer alertar?' | translate}}
  </button>
</ion-item>

presentAlert() {
  let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
    title: '!!* Atenção *!!',
    subTitle: 'Uma mensagem de alerta!',
    buttons: ['Já vou ver...']
  });
  alert.present();
}
```

It works normally at the same app. How can I send this alert to another app?

EDIT: pick-up.html (sender)

```
<ion-item (click)="getDirection(trip.destination.location.lat,trip.destination.location.lng)">
          <h2 class="font-lbr">{{'Destino' | translate}}</h2>
          <p class="font-lbr-p">{{ trip.destination.vicinity }}</p>
          <button color="green" item-right dark ion-button (click)="getDirection(trip.destination.location.lat,trip.destination.location.lng)">
            <ion-icon name="navigate"></ion-icon>&nbsp; {{'Navegar' | translate}}
          </button>
        </ion-item>

        <allow-intent href="receiver://*/*" />

      </ion-list>
```

Now, the "receiver", tracking.ts...

```
playAudio(){
        if(PLAY_AUDIO_ON_REQUEST == true){
          let audio = new Audio(AUDIO_PATH);
          audio.play();
        }
      }

      this.deeplinks.route({
        '/alert': 'Alert',
        '/navigate': 'Navigate',
    }).subscribe(match => {
        if (match.$route === 'Alert') {
            let alertData = {
                title: match.$args['title'],
                subtitle: match.$args['subtitle'],
                button1text: match.$args['button1text']
                button2text: match.$args['button2text']
            }
            presentAlert(alertData);
         }
    }, nomatch => {
        //handle no match
    });

    }
```

That's the right way?

EDIT2: I don't have deeplinks plugin here...

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vth38.png)

Comment: You'll probably need to look into push notifications or sending http requests to a sever which both phones connect to in order to transfer information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the the [deeplinks](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/deeplinks/) plugin. 
Lets assume you have sender and receiver app. 
Receiver app needs to have a unique URL scheme like this
`receiver://alert?title=title&subtitle=subtitle&button1text=buttontext&button2text=button2text`.

Use the code along the lines

```
   this.deeplinks.route({
       '/alert': 'Alert',
       '/navigate': 'Navigate',
   }).subscribe(match => {
       if (match.$route === 'Alert') {
           let alertData = {
               title: match.$args['title'],
               subtitle: match.$args['subtitle'],
               button1text: match.$args['button1text']
               button2text: match.$args['button2text']
           }
           presentAlert(alertData);
        }
   }, nomatch => {
       //handle no match
   });
```

You might require `allow-intent` in sender app

```
<allow-intent href="receiver://*/*" />
```